# How to set a label value inside the input filed with a datalist

Tags: html, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am able to create an input field with a datalist in *html5* with *Reactjs*. The reactjs code looks like this:

```
const Container = props => {
  const countryList = props.countries.map(c => <option key={c} value={c} />);

  return (
    <div>
      <input list="countries" name="Country" />
      <datalist id="countries">{countryList}</datalist>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This code is proved to work properly, say the input field is there and if user type something in the field, relevant list will show. The problem is that the input field is empty without any label. So an indicator for telling what the field is about is needed, for instance, a label can be added to the left side or the top of the input field, but this would take more space on the page.

Therefore, **I would like to add some light-colored text indicator/label inside the input field, and when user click this input field, the text indicator would disappear and the user can insert value and also get data list**

Anyone can give some suggestion on how to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input list="countries" name="Country" placeholder="sometext"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I want :)